# LWJGL openGL immediate mode vs pure java

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Like the title says, what render method would you recommend for a 2D top-down game to get the best performence?

Would you use LWJGL to use openGL immediate rendering mode or pure java?

Comment: The best performance might be achieved with OpenGL. But I would definitely use core profile rendering, since immediate mode is outdates for several years now.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure java"?

Comment: with "pure java" i mean javas swing library!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using neither the Java Swing/AWT library or the LWJGL (In it's immediate form). I would personally recommend using either [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) or [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) libraries as both have really useful features and optimizations that allow for your game to be written much quicker and run much faster.

Comment: ok thats exacly my thought too. I will go with libGDX! Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! Also, when finding an answer, it's customary to mark the answer as such by clicking the tick underneath the up/down vote buttons :)